# Set Dropdown list width in yii2

Tags: yii2, dropdown

How to set Dropdown list width in Yii2, here the code

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'id_ts')
    ->dropDownList( 
        ArrayHelper::map(vision::find()->all(),'id_ts', 'vision'),
        [ 
            'prompt' =>'',
            'disabled' => $model->isNewRecord ? true : false 
        ]
    ) ?>
```

How to make dropdown list box wider ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just add style in `dropDownList` show below code

```
<?= $form
  ->field($model, 'id_ts')
  ->dropDownList( 
    ArrayHelper::map(vision::find()->all(),'id_ts', 'vision'), 
    [
        'style' => 'width:15px !important', 
        'prompt' => '', 
        'disabled' => $model->isNewRecord ? true : false 
    ]
  ) ?>
```